# Implement Velicer's MAP criterion

Tags: algorithm, r, statistics

I'm looking at the [psych package](http://bm2.genes.nig.ac.jp/RGM2/R_current/library/psych/man/00.psych-package.html) and the [VSS tutorial](http://www.personality-project.org/R/html/VSS.html), do I simply replace VSS with MAP? Like this:

```
MAP(x, n = 8, rotate = "varimax", diagonal = FALSE, fm = "pa", n.obs=NULL,plot=TRUE,title="Very Simple Structure",...)
```

or is there another way to do this?

I've doing factor analysis right now and I'm using the elbow method on a scree plot. I'm trying to see if I can try to use Velicer's MAP criterion also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the documentation for that function using `?MAP`.

If there is nothing there, probably send an email to the author, listed at the package's CRAN page:
[CRAN Page for Psych](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/psych/index.html)

That package is made by the folks at this site. They probably have a mailing list:
[PersonalityProject.org](http://personality-project.org/r)

Answer (score 2):

@Ryan Rosario

I finally figured it out:

```
install.packages("psych")
library("psych")
```

I ran the sample steps

```
my.VSS <- VSS(test.data,title="VSS of 24 mental tests")
```

and

```
VSS(sim.circ(nvar=24),fm="mle", title="VSS of 24 circumplex variables")
```

and

```
VSS(sim.item(nvar=24),fm="mle", title="VSS of 24 circumplex variables")
```

you get something like this as output (for the last input):

Very Simple Structure of  VSS of 24 circumplex variables 
Call: VSS(x = sim.item(nvar = 24), fm = "mle", title = "VSS of 24 circumplex variables")
VSS complexity 1 achieves a maximimum of 0.84  with  **3  factors**
VSS complexity 2 achieves a maximimum of 0.87  with  **8  factors**

The Velicer MAP criterion achieves a minimum of 0.05  with  **2  factors**

Velicer MAP
[1](http://bm2.genes.nig.ac.jp/RGM2/R_current/library/psych/man/VSS.html) 0.05 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.02 0.02 0.02

Very Simple Structure Complexity 1
[1](http://bm2.genes.nig.ac.jp/RGM2/R_current/library/psych/man/VSS.html) 0.44 0.84 0.84 0.80 0.75 0.76 0.80 0.80

Very Simple Structure Complexity 2
[1](http://bm2.genes.nig.ac.jp/RGM2/R_current/library/psych/man/VSS.html) 0.00 0.85 0.85 0.85 0.86 0.86 0.86 0.87

as the [documentation says](http://bm2.genes.nig.ac.jp/RGM2/R_current/library/psych/man/VSS.html) (highlighting above is mine):

> "Wayne Velicer's MAP criterion has
>   been added as an additional test for
>   the optimal number of components to
>   extract. Note that VSS and MAP will
>   not always agree as to the optimal
>   number."

In this case VSS with complexity of 1 and 2 gives an answer of 3 and 8 factors respectively while Velicer's MAP criterion gives 2.

Answer (score 2):

A late response, but I thought I'd follow up to pageman's comment. Let's say you create an object with the vss function:

```
my.vss <- vss(test.data)
```

The summary function will provide the VSS and MAP criterion results, e.g.,

```
summary(my.vss)
```

but you can easily pull out the MAP results from the object as well (like I needed to when running VSS and MAP criterion tests over many datasets), like so:

```
#returns the number of factors recommended by MAP
which(my.vss$map == min(my.vss$map))   

#returns the number of factors recommended by VSS for complexity 1
which(my.vss$cfit.1 == max(my.vss$cfit.1)

#returns the number of factors recommended by VSS for complexity 2
which(my.vss$cfit.2 == max(my.vss$cfit.2))
```

There are also a whole bunch of fun stats hanging out inside of the vss.stats data.frame with in the vss object, i.e.,

```
class(my.vss$vss.stats)
```